# Scrapy only returns first result

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape preformatted html seen [here](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&appid=440).
But my code only returns 1 price instead of all 10 prices.

Code seen here:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "working1"
    allowed_domains = ["steamcommunity.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&appid=440"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        price = sel.xpath("//text()[contains(.,'$')]").extract()[0].replace('\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t','')
        print price
```

I'm super new to scrapy/xpath so I'm not really sure why it isn't printing every instance of the price.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why's the `[0]` in there if you want all the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the first result of the xpath match. Instead, iterate over all of them:

```
for price in sel.xpath("//text()[contains(., '$')]").extract():
    print price.strip(r"\r\n\t")
```

Prints (there are multiple occurrences of `$0.03`):

```
$0.03
$0.03
$0.03
$0.03
$0.03
$0.03
$0.03
$0.03
$0.03
$0.03
```

Comment: Fantastic! What about if I want to return rather than print? Thanks again!

Comment: @5Y3WS this is when you need to create an `Item` class with `Field`(s) and return instances of that `Item` from your `parse()` method.