# Scrapy code returns only first result, attempts to enter relative path have been unsuccessful

Tags: python, scrapy

I am very new to python and scrapy.
I have an otherwise successful script parsing a report that I have downloaded for offline use and providing a spreadsheet with about 15 values for each item in a list.
However, one item is eluding me:
Source is:

```
<div class="word1 word2">£{price} *</div>
```

My code is:

```
{mainheading}s = response.css('div.{mainheading}')
```

...

```
for item in {mainheading}s:
    {word1 word2_variable} = response.xpath(".//div[@class = 'word 1 word2']").get()
```

Noting that there is a space in the identifier, I have tried to use css for this and have not been able to retrieve any results. Is there a way to use css for this?

xpath has had limited success in that the first value is reported. getall reports all the values as expected, but the format will be very difficult to work with as I will have a list of values in every cell within the table column.

I have read 
[Scrapy returns only first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164296/scrapy-returns-only-first-result)
[Scrapy only returns first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481109/scrapy-only-returns-first-result)
and tried using dots (as above) so that I get each relative result and not the first absolute one. However, I get the same result with no dots, one or two. Removing a / results in 'None'.

I have played with this for some time, and sense that I am missing something simple due to lack of knowledge. If there is a simple fix then that will be amazing, but if not a pointer to the area of scrapy/python I need to check up on will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `getall` method instead of `get` Ref https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1

Comment: Thanks Kishan, do you think that given the source code structure and split identifier name I am unlikely to succeed in getting one value for each iteration? As said, getall has been partially successful, but I now have a csv with all the other data (which is outside the scope of my question) properly tabulated and the column for "text1 text2" with the full list of values for each iteration in every cell. If this is the best I can do then I will use VBA to deal with it, but I wanted to know whether I had misunderstood how to use xpath here. As said, I do appreciate your assistance.